# C++: How do you run an executable in windows that uses libcurl?

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, libcurl

I wrote a utility to grab information off the web using libcurl and written and compiled using Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine. I'd like to be able to run the executable in the windows environment, but when I do I get the error "The program can't start because cygcurl-4.dll is missing from your computer." I'm not sure how to resolve this, because even if I install libcurl for windows it seems like it's looking specifically for the Cygwin version. Ideally I'd like to figure out how to make the program self contained so it can function without people having to install any libraries themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The program can't start because cygcurl-4.dll is missing from your computer."
You only need to distribute cygcurl-4.dll with your executable to solve this (put the dll into the same folder).

It should be located in the binaries folder of Cygwin.

Comment: There also seem to be about 90 other .DLLs that it needs. It worked when I copied 90MB of cygwin DLLs, but that's sort of inconvenient and I wasn't sure why a lot of them were neccesary. Do you know why this might be / how to avoid it?

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay Try linking statically, that should remove the dependency.

Comment: Thank you. How would I do that?

Comment: I tried compiling with the -static tag but it's giving me a whole load of undefined reference errors from libcurl

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your program self-contained, you should try to compile libcurl on Windows as a static library (a .lib file) without cygwin. [Some people say that it is doable](https://www.google.com/search?q=libcurl%20windows). If you're unlucky, maybe you should try [some other similar library](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html).